# What's the totalSupply when using the polygon bridge?

Tags: solidity, polygon, polygon-bridge, totalsupply

I'm deploying a contract on polygon and I'm trying to cap the total supply of the ERC20 token.
My question is how do I know what's the total supply? When withdrawing, some tokens are burnt and cross the bridge, but I can't tell if it happened.

Comment: There's no burn when using the bridge on the native chain

Comment: @0xSanson what’s the native chain? How it works without burning?

Comment: If you deployed it on polygon, the native chain is polygon. The bridge won't burn tokens when transferring them to another chain. Instead they keep the token in a contract (like an escrow), so when someone bridges in there's no need to mint, they pull from that contract

Comment: But how it’s implemented, I know that in withdraw you call your burn function. So for you, you burnt coins you can’t tell the difference

Comment: If your token doesn't need a burn function, just don't write it. As I said, the bridge works fine cause they don't burn/mint.

Comment: Isn’t the whole withdrawal is a proof of burn?

Comment: Not necessarily. Try to bridge something from a native chain and have a look at the transaction